# Reading post data from servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to read post data from a servelet `doPost` method the following way.

1. using `httpservletrequest.getInputStream();`
2. Creating an instance of `bytearrayoutputstream`.
3. writing the post data to `bytearrayoutputstream` from `httpservletrequest.getInputStream()`;
4. Finally, output I'm getting from `bytearrayoutputstream.toByteArray()`.

The problem with that is, when I enter `150/10` in the textfield, `toByteArray` gives me `150%2F10`.
`toByteArray` seems to be encoding the special characters in the output for the `/` character.

What will be the elegant way to read post data from servlet `doPost()` method?

Comment: Use `request.getParameter()`.

Comment: What will be the cause of why toByteArray() encoding special character %2f instead of "/"?

Comment: Special characters in form data sent are url-encoded, the same way as GET parameters are, in order to fit in a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before you pass data to the servlet, try to encode it in client side. or else when you retrieve it, in the servlet, do a Url encode there.

try this way:

```
String abc = URLEncoder.encode("convert my string 150/10", "UTF-8");
byte[] barr = abc.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

use above with the

> request.getParameter();

then you don't have to play with all these fancy codes. I guess when you convert into a byte array, you will have to specify the encoding mechanism to avoid char set ambiguity.

I did not try the above code, but would like you to have a try!

Comment: Thanks  for your response.Actually, toByteArray() seems to be encoding the special character "/". I resolved the issue by doing an decoding mechanisum

Comment: can you post your answer, so it can help others who seek the same !

Comment: URLdecoder.decode(new String(bytearrayoutputstream.toByteArray()),"UTF-8");

Comment: oh, that means my post has supported you to select the URLDecoder right?

Comment: so if really helped, please appreciate it by accepting or up voting brother !!